# How can I make vows wait 60s for a callback to happen

Tags: node.js, vows

I've written some code that connects to an FTP server and lists a very long directory.  It can take 40+ seconds to get a response.

I've written some code to start testing this but I get Errored >> callback not fired.

Is there a way to instruct Vows or Node to just chill for a bit and wait for the callbacks to fire say, up to some configurable amount of time?

Here's my vows code:
     vows.describe('FTP Downloader Suite').addBatch({
       'FTP Downloader' : {
            topic: function() {
                var promise = new(events.EventEmitter);

```
            var lastMomentDownloaded = moment();
            lastMomentDownloaded.subtract('minute', 1);
            ftpDownloader.getNewPathsToDownload(config, lastMomentDownloaded, function(err, res) {
                if (err) { promise.emit('error',   err, res) }
                else   {   promise.emit('success', err, res) }
            });
            return promise;
        },
        'can be accessed': function(err, stat) {
            assert.isNull(err); // we have no error
            assert.isArray(stat); // we have a result
        },
        'is not empty': function(err, stat) {
            assert.isNotZero(stat.length);
        },
        'is shorter than 100 paths': function(err, stat) {
            assert.isTrue(stat.length < 100);
        },
        'contains paths matching the config': function(err, stat) {
            _.each(stat, function(value, key, list) {
                console.log(value);
            });
        }
       }
    }).export(module);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Vows was obfuscating the source of the problem which is that an error was being thrown.  When I switched to nodeunit the issue was obvious.  Maybe there is a way to improve error logging with vows but I'm done with it.